# Can I bake the animation of a mesh and get rid of its armature?

Tags: animation, armature, baking, pose-mode, .fbx

Bare with me since I am not so familiar with the baking animation process.

I have a mesh, where its vertices (and so its faces) get moved as a result of its armature.

There is an animation based on some different poses.

I wanna take this animation to use it in unity. But I don't want to drag the armature with me.

So is it possible to just "bake" the translation (motion) -animation- of the mesh and just drag the object along with its mesh and an animation only?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The word for that kind of thing is "vertex animation". Blender supports shape keys that can be imported into unity via FBX. They are typically used for cloth animation and facial animations that are difficult to do with bones - if you're looking for movement in general then you'd generally want to stick to the armature and use an armature in Unity as well. You could also try to use a different armature in Unity and retarget the animations with Mechanim - if the armatures are compatible Mechanim usually works great.

If you just converted the keyframed poses to shape keys you *might* get an animation that looks roughly like the armature-based animation, but shape keys don't interpolate the same way that bones do. If you **have** to use shape keys you might have to create a shape key for every frame and change the blend shape in Unity in every frame.

You can create a shape key by selecting "Apply as Shape Key" in the armature modifier of the mesh that's controlled by the armature:
[image]

This thread might be of intererest to you:
https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?300572-Is-it-possible-to-bake-armature-poses-into-shape-keys-morph-targets

Comment: The .mdd export suggested in the thread and the application of it as shape keys for a 2nd copy-object is what I wanted, thank you.